# wpf commandtarget for routeduicommand with nested controls

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, routed-commands, nested-controls

I have a main window wich consist mainly of a fluidribbon control as menu and a statusbar.
It also has a content control where i load views (usercontrols).

Im using RoutedUICommand's to execute button events from my Ribbon buttons. Depending on the ribbon buttons action i want them to be executed in the main window or in the loaded view (usercontrol).

My problem is that when i bind my ribbonbutton to a command that is executed inside a loaded usercontrol it seams like it dosen't matter what my commandtarget binding is i always get the usercontrol as sender and source in my ExecutedRoutedEventArgs.

In this particular case i need to get the actuall Fluent.Button so i can modify the text and icon on the button since it is a kinda of toggle button so i wanna swith text from open -> close -> open and the same with associated icons.

At creation of my usercontrol i binds the command:

```
this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(CommandLibrary.InvoiceControl_PreviewToggle, OnPreviewToggle_Command));
```

Then i have my event:

```
private void OnPreviewToggle_Command(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = e.Source as Fluent.Button;
}
```

Then in my main window i got my RibbonButton:

```
<Fluent:Button x:Name="PreviewToggle_Button" Header="Open" Icon="/levscan.wpf.resources;component/Icons/appbar.layer.perspective.up.png" LargeIcon="/levscan.wpf.resources;component/Icons/appbar.layer.perspective.up.png" Command="cmd:CommandLibrary.InvoiceControl_PreviewToggle" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=PreviewToggle_Button}" CanAddToQuickAccessToolBar="False"/>
```

And i always get sender and e.Source = my usercontrol and e.OriginalSource seams to be the currently focused element in my usercontrol.

**Edit**

Found a workaround that solves the issue with the target, i can pass the button as the CommandParameter, that works but i dont think its a solution becourse if i would need to pass an actuall parameter also i would need an actually working target.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out exactly the same problem and was just about to ask this - upvoted. It happens even with a simple `button` if there's an explicit `CommandTarget` on it.